# How to connect a menu item to a container through scroll property in flutter i.e. an anchor in html

Tags: flutter, web

Hello everyone I am new to flutter and I am facing a difficulty in my website development. I have three different classes:

1. Main menu (which is not in my Navbar but a row in my body widget)
2. Menu Items ( dropdown item of a menu item)
3. Carousel slider (item in my body widget)

I want to connect a sub menu item to my carousel slider container using an 'OnTap' function in the sub menu class. It seems the only solution is to combine the widgets but I don't want to since they are not supposed to be close but just linked via a click. In few words I am in search of codes where we have a click on a menu sub-item and the screen context scrolls down to the specific item on the canvas without changing page.

Here a code example:

```
//my main class
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:navigation_scroll/widgets/view/homePage.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

//my homePage class

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:navigation_scroll/widgets/carousels/carouselOne.dart';
import 'package:navigation_scroll/widgets/carousels/carouselTwo.dart';
import 'package:navigation_scroll/widgets/menu/dropDownMenu.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyHomePageState();
  }
}

//where you have the combination of all the widgets
class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(child: Text("ListView")),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 30.0,
              ),

              Container(
            child:ListViewDemo(),
            ),

              SizedBox(
                height: 50.0,
              ),

            Container(
                child: CarouselOne()),
              SizedBox(
                height: 50.0,
              ),
            Container(
                child: CarouselTwo()),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}

import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 // this is the first carousel that appears on screen
class  CarouselOne extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CarouselSlider(
      items: [

        //1st Image of Slider
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage("https://cdn.eso.org/images/thumb300y/eso1907a.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),

        //2nd Image of Slider
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage("https://cdn.eso.org/images/thumb300y/eso1907a.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),

        //3rd Image of Slider
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage("https://cdn.eso.org/images/thumb300y/eso1907a.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),

        //4th Image of Slider
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage("https://cdn.eso.org/images/thumb300y/eso1907a.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),

        //5th Image of Slider
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage("https://cdn.eso.org/images/thumb300y/eso1907a.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),

      ],

      //Slider Container properties
      options: CarouselOptions(
        height: 180.0,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
        autoPlay: true,
        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
        enableInfiniteScroll: true,
        autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
        viewportFraction: 0.8,
      ),
    );
  }
}

import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// this is the second carousel that appears on screen
class  CarouselTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CarouselSlider(
      items: [

        //1st Image of Slider
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage("https://cdn.eso.org/images/thumb300y/eso1907a.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),

        //2nd Image of Slider
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage("https://cdn.eso.org/images/thumb300y/eso1907a.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),

        //3rd Image of Slider
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage("https://cdn.eso.org/images/thumb300y/eso1907a.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),

        //4th Image of Slider
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage("https://cdn.eso.org/images/thumb300y/eso1907a.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),

        //5th Image of Slider
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage("https://cdn.eso.org/images/thumb300y/eso1907a.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),

      ],

      //Slider Container properties
      options: CarouselOptions(
        height: 180.0,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
        autoPlay: true,
        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
        enableInfiniteScroll: true,
        autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
        viewportFraction: 0.8,
      ),
    );
  }
}

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// this is the dropdown menu from which we select and want to arrive at the carousel slider
class ListViewDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return ListViewDemoState();
  }
}

class ListViewDemoState extends State<ListViewDemo> {
  List<String> selectedItemValue = List<String>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
             return Container(
                height: 50.0,
                child: ListView (
                  children: [
                    Center(
                      child: DropdownButton(
                        //value:'ABOUT',
                        onChanged: (value) {  },
                        items: [
                          DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              child: Text(
                                'VISION'
                              ),
                              onTap: (){}, // we need to write a function here that does what we want to a container in the carousel slider
                            ),
                          ),
                          DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: Text(
                              'MISSION'
                            ),
                            onTap: (){}, // we need to write a function here that does what we want to a container in the carousel slider
                          ),
                          DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: Text(
                                'TEAM'
                            ),
                            onTap: (){}, // we need to write a function here that does what we want to a container in the carousel slider
                          ),
                        ],

                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You should share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this with CarouselSlider controller you can trigger it onTap and scroll it to your desired destination

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using `CarouselController` attached with your CarouselSlider.
On Button/Menu click, you just need to call

`carouselController.jumpToPage(whateverYourTargetedPageNoInInt);`